# chrome javascript event handling problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this problem with multiple event handlers being called simultaneously in google chrome.
The following code fires the eventHandler function in case of a bookmark create event.

```
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(eventHandler);
```

When multiple bookmarks are created, for example by dragging a couple of bookmarkbar links from firefox to chrome, multiple *eventHandler* functions are run simultaneously which result in undesirable effects. I need to make sure that only one instance of the *eventHandler* is running at a time and events are handled in first come first served basis. Is there a way in javascript to make sure of this ?

Answer (score 2):

As Jakub noted, asynchronous event handling is one of the nice bits of JavaScript. I'd suggest rethinking your application flow to support this rather than trying to serialize it. Moreover, you aren't promised that the order in which the events fire is the order in which you expect them to fire. Dragging in multiple bookmarks could generate events in arbitrary order.

If you really need to ensure that your program handles things in the order they come in, and only processes one item at a time, you could split your logic into two parts: the `eventHandler` itself could be a function that populates a queue of events that you need to deal with in some way, and you could have another function that runs in a timeout-driven loop, checking the queue, pulling an item off, and processing it. Something like the following (untested) code:

```
function SerializedEventHandler() {
  chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(this.enqueue.bind(this));
}

SerializedEventHandler.prototype = {
  queue_: [],

  timer_: null,

  enqueue: function (e) {
    this.queue_.push(e);
    this.startProcessing();
  },

  startProcessing: function () {
    if (!this.timer_)
      this.timer_ = setTimeout(this.process.bind(this), 100);
  },

  process: function () {
    if (this.queue_.length) {
      var item = this.queue_.shift();
      // do something with `item`
      this.timer_ = clearTimeout(this.timer_);
      this.startProcessing();
    }
  }
};
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: order is important to avoid race conditions.though i havent tested your code yet, i think i'll go with this approach. is there a possibility that some events pass by when the time is being set ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a really elegant way to do this. The whole point of JavaScript is that it is event based.

A way to hack it might be using `setTimeout` with a very short timeout.

```
var timeout;

chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(function(ev) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {eventHandler(ev);}, 5);
});
```

Comment: even with delays, output is the same